# Registering dll in GAC

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

Am getting exceptonal error when I try to execute a SSIS package which has script task. The control is not entering into the `Main()` function only and throwing the error. Below is the error details..

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

When I explored I came to know that we need to register dlls which are reference in GAC. But when I try to do that using command line there also am getting invalid command errors. Used below 2 commands to register. Please let me know how can I resolve this issue. What command I need to fire to register the dll. Am using .Net 4.0 framework.

```
gacutil -i Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll

gacutil.exec /l "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll"
```

Comment: When you go to register the dll, is your error message "'gacutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting `invalid command errors`, that mean you are not executing this command under `Framework SDK`. You need to follow this to execute.

GacUtil is part of the Framework SDK 4.0 version ( just for your purpose i have used v 4 here) is located at C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
 Just set up a batch file like:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\gacutil -i <DLL_Path>
PAUSE 'Any key to finish'
```

Or just execute this `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\gacutil -i <DLL_Path>`

Comment: In my system gacutil files were @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools which I moved to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 and executed the commands, it get executed without any error. However am still facing the same exception in SSIS package execution. Do  I need to do anything else after dll registration?

Comment: Check that assembly registered or not , - windows-run-type `assembly`- if it there , then it is  installed, but i am not sure about the SSIS error, NOTE: i was just say, mostly gacutil should be present in `\Framework\v4.0.30319` , if you find it somewhere else, you could have executed there, no need to move it somewhere else.